# How select an attribute inside list using css selector and Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, css-selectors

I'm trying to use css selector to get an element inside a `<li>` with Selenium

That's I have:

```
<div id= "popup">
  <ul>
     <li>
        <div id="item" option= "1" ....> </div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <div id="item" option= "2" ....> </div>
     </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I need to get the second div, with option=2. I tried:

```
webdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#popup > ul li:nth-child(n) [option=2]");
```

that works fine in console of Chrome but not with Selenium :/ What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- `:nth-child(n)` means "*any* value of n" which will result in *every* child being matched. You probably mean to use `:nth-child(2)` if you want to make sure you only get the element under the second `li`. Or if it doesn't matter which `li` it appears in, you can get rid of the `:nth-child()` selector entirely.
- The value in an attribute selector must be quoted if it begins with a digit, so `[option='2']`.

The correct selector, therefore, is:

```
webdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#popup > ul li:nth-child(2) [option='2']");
```

Comment: Yeah  "#popup > ul li:nth-child(2) [option='2']" work´s fine, but i need select element with [option='2'] but i dont know position in the list. :nth-child() does not work.

Finaly i use: "#popup > ul li [option='2']" and works fine in console and selenium

Comment: @bott: I did mention that in my answer. I knew I should have added the other option to go with the explanation just in case...

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
"#popup > ul li [option='2']"
```

works fine in console and selenium!